# mode2 command not found

Tags: linux, arm, lirc

I was trying to load LIRC GPIO on raspberry pi. When trying this

```
mode2 -d /dev/lirc0
```

it gives

```
-bash: mode2: command not found
```

Do I need to install something to support it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PATH is not finding the mode2 executable. [Standard install procedure](http://alexba.in/blog/2013/01/06/setting-up-lirc-on-the-raspberrypi/) on RPi includes:

```
apt-get install lirc
```

[Setup LIRQ](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO%3aSetup_Lirc) has information that could be helpful if it still needs troubleshooting.